# get JSON object data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a below JSON object how can i access data with jquery?Do we need to parse it

**JSON**

```
{
    "1": {
        "Name": "john ",
        "age": 32
    },
    "2": {
        "Name": "David ",
        "age": 30
    },
    "3": {
        "Name": "Maxim ",
        "age": 35
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question is too broad, provides no attempt at a solution of your own, it's a duplicate, it's unclear... the list can go on and on.

Comment: there have multiple threads about this topic , u can find those things by search. and what u need to do here. what u really expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved your question with javascript in this fiddle:-

```
    var json = { "1": { "Name": "john ", "age": 32 }, "2": { "Name": "David ", "age": 30 }, "3": { "Name": "Maxim ", "age": 35 }};

    for(var i in json){
       console.log(json[i].Name);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vtgm3489/

Comment: If you want to access in any other way then eleborate your question please.

Comment: Its blank...URL is jsfiddle's home url

Comment: I have a json data and i want to list down name and age in my html page

Comment: Now check it again https://jsfiddle.net/vtgm3489/

Comment: I am accessing name in this code.you can use json[i].age to access the age

Comment: Hi, did it solve your problem? @hareesh

Comment: Hi, if it solved your problem then mark it as an answer.thank you

Comment: Thank Muhammad its solved